# How To Upload Same image in multiple folders Nodejs multer

Tags: node.js, file-upload, imagemagick, multer

How to Upload Same Image In Different Folder At Same Time?
I was Tried below but not worked But when Upload in one folder it will work.

```
var multer  = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({

    destination: (req, file, cb) => {

        cb(null, 'public/images/image')

        cb(null, 'public/images/pic')
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {

        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)

        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix+'.png')

    }

});

const cpUpload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

On frontend:

```
<input type = "file" name="image" />

<button>Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multer expects a single filename from the destination()-function. So that approach wouldn't work. You could pass single directory in destination(), and then in your controller, after multer has processed the file upload request, copy the uploaded file from one location to other locations using fs.copyFile().

Answer (score 0):

For the same Requirement, below nodejs code is working for me.

```
  pool.query('SELECT first_name FROM users where user_pk = 1', (err,rows) => {
      if(err) throw err;
        rows.forEach( (row) => {
        //console.log(`${row.first_name}`);
        var fname = (`${row.first_name}`);
        console.log('First Name is : ' + fname);
        //let fname = req.first_name;
    
    
    var dateObj = new Date();
    //var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
    var month = dateObj.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    
    
    datewise = "datewise" + "/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/" + fname;
    empwise  = "empwise"  + "/" + fname + "/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
    
        });`enter code here`
      });  
      
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        let Id = req.body.id;
        let datewisepath = `/RestAPIUpload/${datewise}`;
        let empwisepath = `/RestAPIUpload/${empwise}`;
            fs.mkdirsSync(datewisepath);
            fs.mkdirsSync(empwisepath);     
        cb(null, datewisepath);
        cb(null, empwisepath);
        // callback(null, 'uploads/' + req.user.id);
      },
     /* filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now());
      }
    });
    */
    
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        // console.log(file);
        let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
        let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
        cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + extension);
        console.log(req.file);
     }
    })
    var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('dataFile',50);
    
    app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
        upload(req,res,function(err) {
            console.log(req.body);
            console.log(req.files);
            if(err) {
                return res.end("Error uploading file.");
            }
            res.end("File is uploaded");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Your multer code like below it should be work:

```
const currentTIme =  Date.now();
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const uploadDirs = ['uploads', 'uploads/posts'];
        uploadDirs.forEach((dir) => {
            const destinationPath = dir;
            cb(null, destinationPath);
        });
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, currentTIme + '-' + file.originalname);
    },
});
```

And if your want to save in different name then it should be like:

```
const currentTIme =  Date.now();
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const uploadDirs = ['uploads', 'uploads/posts'];
        uploadDirs.forEach((dir) => {
            const destinationPath = dir;
            cb(null, destinationPath);
        });
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + + '-' + file.originalname);
    },
});
```